# wp7 xna flood fill Texture2D algorithm

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, flood-fill

I need to flood fill a texture2D in WP7 XNA.

I am looking for piece of code for it that i use in WP7 XNA.

any idea?

Comment: I'd suggest using using `texture.GetData` and doing a standard flood fill algorithm then using `texture.SetData`.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/39560/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue solved.

i have uploaded the sample code on code project.

[WP7 FloodFill in Texture2D using Scan line Stack Algo](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/320628/WP7-FloodFill-in-Texture2D-using-Scan-line-Stack-A)